# Python is printing 0x90c2 instead of just 0x90 NOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, no-op

The following command is outputting 200 bytes of 'A' followed by one byte of 0x0a:

```python
python3 -c "print('\x41'*200)" > out.txt
```

`hexdump out.txt` confirms this:

```
0000000 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141
*
00000c0 4141 4141 4141 4141 000a
00000c9
```

However, whenever I try to output 200 bytes of NOP sled (0x90), for some reason, python decides to also add a series of 0xc2 after every 0x90.  So I'm running this:

```python
python3 -c "print('\x90'*200)" > out.txt
```

And according to `hexdump out.txt`:

```
0000000 90c2 90c2 90c2 90c2 90c2 90c2 90c2 90c2
*
0000190 000a
0000191
```

This is not an issue in perl as the following outputs 200 bytes of NOP sled:

```perl
perl -e 'print "\x90" x 200' > out.txt
```

Why is Python outputting 0x90 followed by 0xc2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Python code resolved the issue:

```bash
python3 -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x90'*200)" > out.txt
```

This is confirmed by `hexdump -C out.txt`:

```
00000000  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  |................|
*
000000c0  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90                           |........|
000000c8
```

Answer (score 2):

You are outputting a `str`, with a codec like utf8, for *text* output.

Prefer to output `bytes` when *binary* output is of interest, and use binary mode.

```
$  python3 -c "b = bytes('\x90' * 4, 'latin1'); print(len(b))"
4
$  python3 -c "b = bytes('\x90' * 4, 'utf-8');  print(len(b))"
8
```

---

Python2, and perl, conflate the two.
Python3 draws a strong distinction between
a sequence of unicode codepoints and a serialized sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You're not printing 200 `\x90` bytes and a `\x0a` byte. You're printing 200 U+0090 DEVICE CONTROL STRING *characters*, and a newline character. Those characters get encoded to bytes in whatever encoding `sys.stdout` is set to, which appears to be UTF-8 here.

If you want to write bytes to a file, open it in binary mode and write a bytestring:

```
with open('out.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'\x90'*200 + b'\n') # you can leave the b'\n' off if you don't want it
```